# Cómo mostrar una alerta al presionar un boton (sin un formulario)?

Tags: javascript, html, botón

Estoy usando html para diseño web. Cómo mostrar una alerta al presionar un boton (sin un formulario, sólo un botón)?

```
        <button onclick="boton1">
              No presiones este boton
            </button>
              <script>
                alert ("alerta")
                </script>
```

Este es el codigo que use pero nu funciona que otra cosa puedo usar?

Comment: Pon el código por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si usas javascript, lo mejor seria ponerle un id al boton, y efectuarlo dentro del script.

```js
document.getElementById('boton1').onclick = function(){
    alert('Hey Alerta Wey!');
}
```

```html
<button id="boton1">
  No presiones este boton
</button>
```

Comment: Gracias, pero lo de (document.getElement.........)el ID en donde lo pongo

Answer (score 1):

Primera aproximación:

```html
<button onclick="alert('alerta');">
  No presionar
</button>
```

Segunda aproximación, más ordenada:

```html
<button onclick="alertar('segunda alerta');">
  No presionar
</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function alertar(texto) {
       alert(texto);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si solo deseas mostrar un alert, puedes usar este ejemplo sencillo, el cual esta disponible en w3school. Te dejo los links por si deseas entender mas a fondo.
[How to create alert button](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_alert_buttons.asp)
[JS Popup](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert("I am an alert box!");
}
```

```css
.btn {
  border: none; /* Remove borders */
  color: white; /* Add a text color */
  padding: 14px 28px; /* Add some padding */
  cursor: pointer; /* Add a pointer cursor on mouse-over */
}

.default {background-color: #e7e7e7; color: black;} /* Gray */
.default:hover {background: #ddd;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>JavaScript Alert</h2>
    <button class="default" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```